# Example of adopting/implementing fast enumeration for my class?

Tags: objective-c, fast-enumeration

I'm trying to understand how to adopt the fast enumeration protocol (under iOS/objective C) for a class I'm creating.  I read the section of Apple's docs, but... I don't quite get it!

Anyone have some sample code I could look at?

What I'm trying to do:  I have an array of objects over which I want a sender to iterate.  The sender wants to use a for-in construct.  The catch is I don't want the sender to see *all* the objects in the array because some of them aren't valid in the context of the application.

In other words, I want my iterator to return a subset of objects in the array matching certain criteria.

I'd prefer not to create any *new* arrays in the process so as not to slow things down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple's own [FastEnumerationSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FastEnumerationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrates it quite well. From the sounds of it, you may not have seen it yet.

There's also [this blog post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-16-implementing-fast-enumeration.html).

Comment: Great!  Yeah, I hadn't seen that.  Thanks!

Comment: That blog post is technically very accurate, but very poorly written. It jumps around in things you don't need to know, and shows things you shouldn't be doing, massively obscuring the things you do need to know. Mike Ash's posts are usually much higher quality :(. I've read it many times, and it's still incomprehensible - I recommend not bothering. Better to hack at the Apple source until you can guess your way to understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

Much better explanation here:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/05/implementing-countbyenumeratingwithstat.html

NB: Apple's source code is technically correct, but poorly explained, and mostly useless unless you enjoy playing "guess what the programmer was thinking / smoking that day".

Liekwise, Mike Ash's post is correct, and useful *after you know how to do it*, but terrible as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "sender wants to use a for-in construct". The outcome you're asking for would probably be better achieved by using indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:, which will give you an index set of all the items in your array that pass whatever test you have set up for it.

You could also use filteredArrayUsingPredicate: to derive a new array that's a subset of your original -- I know you said you didn't want to create any new arrays, but if you want to return a subset of your array, then you have to create a new array.